# how to use cat command in execl system call to create a text file?

Tags: c, linux, shell, ubuntu, system-calls

How can i create text file with the cat command using the execl system call in c

i tried using

```
execl("/bin/cat", "cat", ">", "test.txt", NULL);
```

but it is giving me input output error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that redirection with `>` is handled by the shell that invokes `cat`, not by `cat` itself.  The simplest solution is to invoke `sh` instead, and let it invoke `cat` and handle the redirection:

```
execl("/bin/sh", "sh", "-c", "/bin/cat > test.txt", (char *) NULL);
```

The alternative would be to open the file yourself (with `open`), close standard output, duplicate the file descriptor onto fd 1 (by calling `dup2`), and finally close the first file descriptor.  Then you could call `execl`, letting `cat` write to standard output.  That's basically what the shell does, but it's much easier to let `sh` do it for you.